# JQuery Ajax error when call server side method in asp C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to call server side method using ajax in asp C# application.

i have the following code in aspx file

```
function editApp(appID) {     
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetSquare",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{}",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },

            error: function () {
                alert("Ajax Error"); 
            }
        });
}
```

and the following code in aspx.cs file

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetSquare()
    {
        return "OK";
    }
```

but in each time i call editApp function i get the following alert "Ajax Error"

Comment: Try getting rid of the data type. It looks to me you are expecting a json but your server method is not returning a json.

Comment: Change error part like this and update your question with error message:
    `error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }`

Comment: And put breakpoint inside GetSquare method and run the application. And see if it hits the breakpoint or not?

Comment: Please remove `data: "{}",`

Comment: change -  data: "{ }" to data: { } and come back to us

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not passing any parameters, mentioning as `data: "{}"` is giving you errors. Instead you have to specify as `data: {}` as shown below.

```
function editApp(appID) {     
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetSquare",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },

            error: function () {
                alert("Ajax Error"); 
            }
        });
}
```